# Evidence needed for damages

Tags: nevada

A gang beat me up and incurred  a $1200 medical bill. Police  filed charges but did not arrest.

What evidence do I need to file a civil lawsuit  over the bill? They probably deleted the door camera footage. I have a police officer and his body cam showing my injuries, a medical bill, but no direct witnesses  to the event. Is it enough to show that this huge group of guys standing around me and me being injured? Or is that not conclusive evidence? If I can order the amazon go camera footage  and find it was deleted does that make them look bad on  destroying evidence?

For clarity they invited me over to their house to return a car they stole which is a separate case, then kidnapped and attacked me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need whatever evidence you need to prove your case on the balance of probabilities

You have to decide on what legal basis you are seeking to recover damages; presumably [Battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(tort)).

Each cause of action has elements that you need to prove. Some of these elements may be conceded by the defendant - if so, you don't need any evidence at all. If the elements are contested then you will provide evidence and they will provide evidence and the more probative and convincing evidence wins with ties going to the defendant.

Comment: Is the hospital bill evidence

Comment: @user31215 sure - it’s evidence you went to hospital and what that cost. It’s not evidence you were battered nor of who did it.

Comment: So no thrn.....